# Java Video Chat applicataion input output stream not working

Tags: java, networking, video, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I am making a video chat app which uses java networking (aka. sockets) to send images of the webcam to another client.

My code sends first the length of the buffered image data then the actual data. The Server also reads first a int then the data itself. The first image worked but after it, the data input stream read a negative number as the length.

Server side:

```java
frame = new JFrame();
        while (true) {
            try {

                length = input.readInt();
                System.out.println(length);
                imgbytes = new byte[length];
                input.read(imgbytes);
                imginput = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgbytes);
                img = ImageIO.read(imginput);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
            catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Client side:

```java
while(true) {
            try {

                    currentimg = webcam.getImage();
                    ImageIO.write(currentimg, "jpg", imgoutputstream);
                    imgbytes = imgoutputstream.toByteArray();
                    out.writeInt(imgbytes.length);
                    out.write(imgbytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are running into an infinite loop without a breaking condition at the client side. What will make you break from the inner while loop to read a new image from the webcam inside the outer loop?

Comment: I corrected the error but still it doesn't work. I added a debug `System.out.println()` in the Server side to print the length and here is the output `4465
8917
13388
17869
22323
26786
31233
35694
40168
44637
49116
53596
58062
62546
67038
-657982985
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
 at ServerSide.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:39)
 at ServerSide.Server.<init>(Server.java:42)
 at ServerSide.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:7)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On client side you always write the new image to the existing stream. That leads to an increasing array size in every iteration. In java `int` has a maximum of `2147483647`. If you increase this integer it skips to the minimum value auf `int` which is negative (see [this article](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/integer-overflow)).

So to fix this error you need to clear your stream before writing the next image so the size is never greater than integer's max value.